# Remove word proofing errors from WordML and merge the nodes

Tags: xslt

I am new to XML.
I have a WML file. I need to remove the word proofing errors from the file and merge the split up nodes.
For e.g. the WML file (with word proofing errors on) is as follows (I have removed few lines of code for convenience):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml=...
..
..
</wsp:rsids></w:docPr><w:body>

<w:p wsp:rsidR="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidRDefault="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidP="00FD5EDD">
<w:r><w:t>It are </w:t></w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
<w:r><w:t>dcoument</w:t></w:r>
   <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
   <w:r><w:t> .</w:t></w:r>
   <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
   </w:p>
   <w:p wsp:rsidR="00B67D59" wsp:rsidRDefault="0071345A"/>

   <w:sectPr wsp:rsidR...
   ...
   </w:sectPr></w:body></w:wordDocument>
```

My output should look like (the one we get with word proofing errors off):

```
   ....
   <w:p wsp:rsidR="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidRDefault="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidP="00FD5EDD">
   <w:r><w:t>It are dcoument .</w:t></w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p wsp:rsidR="00B67D59" wsp:rsidRDefault="003B7608"/>
   ...
```

The WML files (one with word proofing errors off and the other with word proofing errors on) should be exactly the same. My requirement is to compare XML files and so I have to remove the discrepancies introduced due to these proofing errors.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think a similar question was asked yesterday. Couldn't find it though.

Comment: hey guys someone plz help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:proofErr]/w:r[1]">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>
        <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
        </w:t>
    </w:r>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:p[w:proofErr]/w:r[position() > 1]"/>
```

**Output**

```
  <w:p wsp:rsidR="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidRDefault="00FD5EDD" wsp:rsidP="00FD5EDD">
      <w:r>
         <w:t>It are dcoument .</w:t>
      </w:r>
   </w:p>
   <w:p wsp:rsidR="00B67D59" wsp:rsidRDefault="0071345A"/>
```