# Remove word proofing errors from WordML

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the same problem as [Remove word proofing errors from WordML and merge the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939898/remove-word-proofing-errors-from-wordml-and-merge-the-nodes) -- to which @Rupesh_Kr provided a suggested xsl template. How do I use it (insufficient reputation to ask there)? What I hope it does is remove the Microsoft Word XML tags proofErr w:type="spellStart" and w:type="spellEnd" that break lines in my document. I currently use XSL to produce more diff'able results by adding carriage returns so I tried to replace that with his and use the command "msxsl.exe -xe procedure.xml xml.xsl" where xml.xsl contains his suggestion but get the following error:

```
Code:   0xc00ce01d
URL:    file:///xml.xsl
Line:   17
Column: 12
Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'w'.
```

xml.xsl contains his suggestion as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!--
   ! This is an XML to XML transformation intended to be imported into a host
   ! XSLT.  The source .xml file is copied verbatim by default.
   ! The importing XSL Transform should specify xsl:output as xml, and should
   ! contain templates to override the node and attribute match made here so
   ! that it can transform specific portions of the original XML file.
    -->

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- ========================================================================
    -->
  <xsl:template match="w:p[w:proofErr]/w:r[1]">
      <w:r>
          <w:t>
          <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
          </w:t>
      </w:r>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:p[w:proofErr]/w:r[position() > 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An example input file follows, simplified by removing many MS Word definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core">
<w:ignoreSubtree w:val="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2"></w:ignoreSubtree>
<o:DocumentProperties>
<o:Lines>1</o:Lines>
</o:DocumentProperties>
<w:fonts>
</w:fonts>
<w:body>
<wx:sect>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"></w:pStyle>
</w:pPr>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"></w:proofErr>
<w:r>
<w:t>Hellow</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"></w:proofErr>
<w:r>
<w:t> </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"></w:proofErr>
<w:r>
<w:t>world!</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"></w:proofErr>
</w:p>
<w:sectPr>
<w:ftr w:type="odd">
</w:ftr>
</w:sectPr>
</wx:sect>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Desired output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core">
<w:ignoreSubtree w:val="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2"></w:ignoreSubtree>
<o:DocumentProperties>
<o:Lines>1</o:Lines>
</o:DocumentProperties>
<w:fonts>
</w:fonts>
<w:body>
<wx:sect>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"></w:pStyle>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:t>Hellow world!</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:sectPr>
<w:ftr w:type="odd">
</w:ftr>
</w:sectPr>
</wx:sect>
</w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Comment: Try adding this to your `xsl:stylesheet ` opening tag: `xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"`. I am only guessing, you need to show us your input XML to make sure.

Comment: Error Line 31 column 12 is in xml.xsl at the end of his "<w:r>", not in the input XML, but if you need the input let me know.

Comment: By "adding" I presume you mean appending as so: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">`. That resolved the xsl compile error code 0xc00ce01d--but the output was far from expected.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question about that - but read about [mcve] first.

Comment: Edited to simplify with input/output thus changing Line from 31 to 17. Subject goal not met by xsl which removes more than proofErr sections.

Comment: I don't understand the logic that needs to be applied to get the shown output. You can easily remove the `w:proofErr` elements. You can - less easily, but still - remove them along with all nodes in-between the `spellStart` and `spellEnd`. But I don't see how you get `<w:t>Hellow world!</w:t>` from the original `<w:t>Hellow</w:t>` (which is inside a `proofErr` block) and `<w:t>world!</w:t>`. Do you want to combine all `w:t` elements into one, or what? All in all, there seems to be too many questions asked at once.

Comment: **1)** Regarding the logic, you stated the wish well to remove proofing elements and combine intervening elements; perhaps the best to hope for is `<w:t>Hellow</w:t><w:t> </w:t><w:t>world!</w:t>`. **2)** Regarding too many questions, I'm sorry what seems simply clear to me has not been communicated to you; I'm sure edits have clarified doubt. **3)** Regarding the other question, I'm confounded that the similarity is not obvious: "remove the word proofing errors from the file and merge the split up nodes." with input fragmented by proofErr and desired output `<w:t>It are dcoument .</w:t>`.

Comment: The similarity is not obvious because the answer given there does not "remove the word proofing errors from the file and merge the split up nodes." If it did, you wouldn't have to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, removing the `w:proofErr` nodes is trivial: you simply need to add an empty template that matches them:

```
<xsl:template match="w:proofErr"/>
```

The other problem of combining all text into a single `w:t` node is not as trivial. What I am about to do will work for the given example, but could produce unexpected results for other documents - specifically documents with multiple paragraphs (each paragraph will have all its text combined individually).

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="w:t"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- copy all text into the first w:r node -->
<xsl:template match="w:r[1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <w:t>
            <xsl:for-each select="../w:r">
                <xsl:value-of select="w:t"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </w:t>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove other w:r nodes -->
<xsl:template match="w:r[position() > 1]"/>

<!-- remove w:proofErr nodes -->
<xsl:template match="w:proofErr"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve">
  <w:ignoreSubtree w:val="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2"/>
  <o:DocumentProperties>
    <o:Lines>1</o:Lines>
  </o:DocumentProperties>
  <w:fonts/>
  <w:body>
    <wx:sect>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Hellow world!</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:sectPr>
        <w:ftr w:type="odd"/>
      </w:sectPr>
    </wx:sect>
  </w:body>
</w:wordDocument>
```

Comment: Each of the 6 removes leaves an undesired blank line but I can apply it to the 1-line docx before applying line-feeds.

Comment: The docx contain short codes like `<w:ftr w:type="odd"/>` but this XSLT outputs undesired long codes like `<w:ftr w:type="odd"></w:ftr>`.

Comment: Why is your **result** indented and mine not?

Comment: All of these are cosmetics that do not change the semantics of the result. I am afraid you are at the mercy of your specific XSLT processor.

Comment: Indent yes, blanks maybe, codes maybe not because another stylesheet preserves short codes.

Comment: Right about unexpected results with unsimplified input. It removes elements like `<w:separator> <w:continuationSeparator> <w:rPr> <w:br> <w:tab> <w:fldChar...> <w:instrText> <w:noProof>` and even reorders text from around to before blocks like `<w:hlink w:dest=".">`/`<w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink">` and `<w:fldSimple w:instr=" REF _Ref493761052 \r \h ">`.

Comment: No elements other that `w:r` (except the very first one within it parent node) and `w:proofErr` (along with any child nodes they might have) are removed. -- P.S. Please do not post code in comments. If necessary, edit your answer and add an example input that produces unwanted results.